# Return value according to multiple criteria

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I'm having trouble with this formula in Google Sheets. I'm trying to find the date in the cell to the left of the maximum value between two date constraints, however it's currently adding together the dates of both cells that contain the maximum value, how can I get it to just use one of those dates? I have tried index and match but I can't figure it out. I've copied in the formulas in the cells below and an image showing the cells referenced. If anyone can help that would be much appreciated. Thanks.

```
Cell B9 Formula: =ArrayFormula(MAX(IF((A2:A5<=$B$8)*(A2:A5>=$B$7),B2:B5,"")))
Cell B10 Formula: =SUMIFS(A2:A5,A2:A5, ">="&$B$7, A2:A5, "<="&$B$8, B2:B5, "="&B9)
```

[image]

Comment: Use Filter or Query function with SORT formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In B10

```
=query(A2:B5,"select A where A<=DATE'"&TEXT(B8,"yyyy-MM-dd")&"' and A>=DATE'"&TEXT(B7,"yyyy-MM-dd")&"' order by B desc limit 1",0)
```

### Explanation

- `select A where A<=DATE'"&TEXT(B8,"yyyy-MM-dd")&"' and A>=DATE'"&TEXT(B7,"yyyy-MM-dd")&"'` selects all the dates between start date and end date and create an array
- `order by B desc` sorts the result set in descending order of value B
- `LIMIT 1` limitis the result to only one item

Comment: Unfortunately I don't understand how that works but it does so thank you!

Comment: I added some comments in my answer

Answer (score 1):

## Just like what Harun24Hr said, FILTER and QUERY are your friends.

I recreated your scenario in a table that looks like this
[image: picture of a well designed spreadsheet, that looks similar to Mr Bates]

### The Max Value Formula is as follows.

```
=MAX(FILTER(B2:B,A2:A >= C2, A2:A <= D2))
```

If I were to replace the ranges with named ranges for readability it would be.

```
=MAX(FILTER( values, dates >= start_date, dates <= end_date))
```

##### Max Explained

The max formula will determine and return a max value from an array. MAX( array )

##### Filter Explained

The filter function will return an array of values that matches the criteria. we use this in the array field in MAX.

FILTER( array, condition1, condition2... etc)

### The Max Value Date Formula is as follows.

```
=INDEX(FILTER(A2:A,A2:A >= C2, A2:A <= D2),MATCH(F1,FILTER(B2:B,A2:A >= C2, A2:A <= D2),0),1)
```

If I were to replace the ranges with named ranges for readability it would be.

```
=INDEX(FILTER( dates, dates >= start_date, dates <= end_dates), MATCH(max_value, FILTER(values ,dates >= start_date, dates <= end_date),0),1)
```

##### Index Explained

The index function will return a value in an array that is at the inputted row and column. INDEX(range, row, column).

##### Filter 1 Explained

The first filter function will return a list of dates between the min and max values, we are using this as the range in the Index function.

##### Match Explained

The match function returns the first position that it finds the value given in the given array. The value we gave it is the output of the max value field. So it is looking for the max value in the given array MATCH(value, array, is_sorted).

##### Filter 2 Explained

The second filter function is doing what the filter function did in the max value field. It is returning a list of values in between the dates. When the match searches for this value in the list, it will have an index to give to the index function on where the max value's date is.

##### Trailing Values Explained

The 1 at the end of the index function is optional, it is to indicate the the index function that we are looking in the first column of the array we gave it, but because we gave it a one dimensional array and we are already by default looking in the first column. This is completely optional and is just purely preference based.

the 0 at the end of the match formula is to indicate that the data is not sorted. And we want the exact value to be matched. This is not the default behavior of the match function.