# INDEX and MATCH needs to return multiple rows

Tags: google-sheets, lookup

My goal: Report all events occurring in a city (+details) to a separate tab, from a master spreadsheet with events in 20+ cities

> If column R says "Boston" report [client name, date of event, time of event, number of participants, video link, moderator, notes, etc.] into the next available row of Sheet8. Boston will use Sheet8 to see all events happening there as well as relevant details for them.

The formula I have so far is
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$T, MATCH("Boston", Sheet1!$R:$R, 0))

It returns the entire row as desired, but there are two problems:

1. I don't need the ENTIRE row, just certain data points
2. It doesn't return ALL Boston events

I've tried regular LOOKUP and VLOOKUP with a hidden first column (doubled from Column R). I'm no good with Pivot Tables, but I tried those too. INDEX/MATCH seems to be the closest I've come to what I need. Just needs  a LITTLE bit more fine-tuning.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: Mockup with fake info, but here!https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_hr_C3DiyEJAftT9h8vxqIP-eYsNoKdkda-XQSWXju4/edit#gid=1646808715

Comment: You should look here, I answered bringing results by multiple criteria in depth. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69236605/return-value-according-to-multiple-criteria/69237849#69237849

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=FILTER({RAFTs!C:H, RAFTs!M:M, RAFTs!U:V}, RAFTs!$R:$R="CHI")
```

[image]